# Newsletter Problem Reports

Tags: newsletter

After newsletter finished sending, that is a "Newsletter Problem Reports" under the newsletter section:

Error Code: 0
Error text: Please refer to exeption.log

What does this mean?
I checked the email address listed here, most of them are working well.

Thanks.
John

Answer (score 1):

So the error says, Magento find something unexpected happened and it logs that problem for you to refer and hence it requests you to have a look on `exception.log`.

You can find this file at `var/log` directory. This directory will hold magento related log errors. By default Magento uses two log files. They are `exception.log` and `system.log`.

[*This answer is a part of #mageStackDay. It is an event conducted by Magento Community members as part of increasing the question-answer ratio. For more information http://www.magestackday.com/*]